# How do I add event listeners for several elements of the same class?

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

I found a codepen (original link: https://codepen.io/Gutto/pen/GBLPyN?editors=0011) that is a "draggable" scrollable horizontal div. I am trying to learn how to accomplish this if I want several of these scrollable divs instead of just one on a page.

In my code I am using .forEach() to loop through two divs of the same class but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="container boxes" id="items-container">
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;">  </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
</div>
<div class="container boxes">
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;">  </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0;padding:15px; font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.container{
  background: #333;display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding:8px;box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 500px;overflow:auto;
}
.item{
  width: 90%;
  height: 60px;
  margin:60px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
.item:nth-child(even){
  background: #30a57f;
}
.item:nth-child(odd){
  background:#c17a38;
}
```

JS:

```
// const container = document.querySelector('#items-container');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
                
let startY;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
let scrollTop;
let isDown;

container.forEach(function(box) {
  box.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    mouseIsDown(box);
    console.log('Mouse Down')
  });
  box.addEventListener('mouseup', function(box) {
    mouseUp(box);
    console.log('Mouse Up')
  });
  box.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(box) {
    mouseLeave(box);
    console.log('Mouse Leave')
  });
  box.addEventListener('mousemove', function(box) {
    mouseMove(box);
  });
})
// container.addEventListener('mousedown',e => mouseIsDown(e));  
// container.addEventListener('mouseup',e => mouseUp(e))
// container.addEventListener('mouseleave',e=>mouseLeave(e));
// container.addEventListener('mousemove',e=>mouseMove(e));

function mouseIsDown(e){
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
  startX = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = container.scrollLeft;
  scrollTop = container.scrollTop; 
}
function mouseUp(e){
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseLeave(e){
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseMove(e){
  if(isDown){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Move vertcally
    const y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
    const walkY = y - startY;
    container.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;

    //Move Horizontally
    const x = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
    const walkX = x - startX;
    container.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walkX;

  }
}
```

Comment: Your `mouseIsDown` and `mouseMove` functions refers to a variable called `container` - thes are the only 2 place it appears in the script, so you get an error saying `"uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined"`. If you're trying to reference the container in which the mouse events are being generated, you'll need to identify it in those two functions. You'll either be on the element itself, or on one of it's children (div.item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues with your code:

First, the `addEventListener` are calling the helper functions with `box` as a parameter. This will not have the information it is expecting (for instance `pageY`). The correct parameter is the event. You can do this like the original code:

```
box.addEventListener('mousedown', e => mouseIsDown(e));
```

or more simply:

```
box.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseIsDown);
```

which will not create a new function, will just call the existing function with `event` as the parameter.

The second is that inside the helper functions the global variable `container` will not have the information you need (for instance `scrollTop`). You should replace it with `box`, passing it as a parameter, or more simply `event.currentTarget` which will be assigned to the correct element.

Here's a working code:

```js
// const container = document.querySelector('#items-container');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
                
let startY;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
let scrollTop;
let isDown;

container.forEach(function(box) {
  box.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseIsDown);
  box.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
  box.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave);
  box.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
})

function mouseIsDown(e){
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
  startX = e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
  scrollTop = e.currentTarget.scrollTop; 
}
function mouseUp(e){
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseLeave(e){
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseMove(e){
  if(isDown){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Move vertcally
    const y = e.pageY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const walkY = y - startY;
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;

    //Move Horizontally
    const x = e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const walkX = x - startX;
    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walkX;

  }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;padding:15px; font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.container{
  background: #333;display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding:5;box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 110px;overflow:auto;
}
.item{
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  margin:8px 2px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
.item:nth-child(even){
  background: #30a57f;
}
.item:nth-child(odd){
  background:#c17a38;
}
```

```html
<div class="container boxes" id="items-container">
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"></div>
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container boxes">
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"></div>
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 150%;"></div>
</div>
```